# Cannot fit screen for tbl_df of dplyr in RStudio Server

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio-server

I am using RStudio server (Version 0.98.994) and dplyr (See session infor below). But print tbl_df object cannot fit the screen. There are always more characters at the end of each row (See red line at the scroonshot)

[image]

I have checked browsers: print tbl_df object is working for Firefox without zooming, but not for Chrome and Internet Explorer. The browser history are clean before checking.

Thanks for any suggestions to fix it.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C       
 [7] LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] hflights_0.1     dplyr_0.4.1.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] DBI_0.3.1      Rcpp_0.11.3    assertthat_0.1 magrittr_1.5   parallel_3.1.1 tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: This is a known bug in RStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it might just be a result of the `tbl_df` print method, which truncates the first column even further when the space is very tight.

Here's the snippet from `dplyr:::trunc_mat`, which is used in `dplyr:::print.tbl_df`

```
... 
rownames(df) <- NULL
is_list <- vapply(df, is.list, logical(1))
df[is_list] <- lapply(df[is_list], function(x) vapply(x, 
    obj_type, character(1)))
mat <- format(df, justify = "left")
width <- width %||% getOption("dplyr.width", NULL) %||% getOption("width")
values <- c(format(rownames(mat))[[1]], unlist(mat[1, ]))
names <- c("", colnames(mat))
w <- pmax(nchar(values), nchar(names))
cumw <- cumsum(w + 1)
too_wide <- cumw[-1] > width
if (all(too_wide)) {
    too_wide[1] <- FALSE
    df[[1]] <- substr(df[[1]], 1, width)
}
...
```

You could probably adjust one or more of the arguments to `trunc_mat()` and `print.tbl_df()`, or try printing the table using a different print method.

You can also try adjusting the dplyr print options, which are something like

```
> grep("dplyr", names(options()), value=TRUE)
[1] "dplyr.print_max"  "dplyr.print_min"  "dplyr.strict_sql"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I try to adjust width argument in print.tbl_df, but still get the same problem. It seems chrome and firefox return different values of getOptions('width'), i.e. 193 for firefox, 221 for chrome (both are full width).

Comment: You might try truncating your column names.  `dplyr` uses a width option that is dependant on column width

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Now I know how to print it through adjusting arguments of print.tbl_df. But it seems there is a bug in the RStudio Server. I will report to github and paste a link here.

Comment: Try the shorter column names too, see if that helps at all